# Using main and delta indexes in sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Im switching fulltext searching on my site to sphinx. Im going to be using SphinxSE to perform the searches.

I created 2 indexes, as specified in the manual: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#live-updates

It seems to work, and index different stuff in its own index, but Im somewhat confused about how I should handle the index updating, merging, and rebuilding.

The way I understand is I cron it to run "indexer delta --rotate" every 5 mins or so, which would add new submissions to the index. Then once a day, I would merge the delta index into the main index by running "indexer main delta --rotate". then once a month or so, I'll run "indexer --all" to rebuild all indexes.

Am I doing this right, or am I  missing something?

Comment: For the record - that's pretty much my setup, all via cron. +1 for asking though, as I've been sketched on how it is currently running. Lets hear those best practices!

Comment: Its just each time you run any of those commands.... wouldn't the search stop working while its running?

Comment: Well, in my case.. indexer --all --rotate --config /path/to/sphinx.conf executes in 0.024 seconds (75k docs per second, running 5 indexes for 4 domains). If my indexes grow significantly I'd have a problem.

Comment: This question is tagged incorrectly.  thinking-sphinx should just be sphinx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--rotate would just build index in tmp (need  space disk) and  switch + restart searchd when it's done.

about delta, you need to use pre-query to compute the "limit" max(id)
 the  main indexes id below the limit, and  delta is up to this limit.

if you have a timestamp (indexed if possible) you can use it

main  -> where timefile < today()
delta -> where timefile >= today()

Answer (score 3):

Sounds pretty much like the setup I did for a customer.  And no, the search won't stop working during updates.  From the Sphinx docs:

> --rotate is used for rotating indexes. Unless you have the situation where
>   you can take the search function
>   offline without troubling users, you
>   will almost certainly need to keep
>   search running whilst indexing new
>   documents. --rotate creates a second
>   index, parallel to the first (in the
>   same place, simply including .new in
>   the filenames). Once complete, indexer
>   notifies searchd via sending the
>   SIGHUP signal, and searchd will
>   attempt to rename the indexes
>   (renaming the existing ones to include
>   .old and renaming the .new to replace
>   them), and then start serving from the
>   newer files. Depending on the setting
>   of seamless_rotate, there may be a
>   slight delay in being able to search
>   the newer indexes.